# Register by phone number only laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

how are you ?

i'm new in laravel and i'm working in someone project and i want to register by phone number instate of email so m i can login by phone number only but is there any way to register by phone number only and get SMS verification after register

so any one will help me please

this is register controller code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\Auth\Role\Role;
use App\Notifications\Auth\ConfirmEmail;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Auth\User\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ];

        if (config('auth.captcha.registration')) {
            $rules['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'required|captcha';
        }

        return Validator::make($data, $rules);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        /** @var  $user User */
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'confirmation_code' => Uuid::uuid4(),
            'confirmed' => false
        ]);

        if (config('auth.users.default_role')) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => config('auth.users.default_role')]));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  mixed $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if (config('auth.users.confirm_email') && !$user->confirmed) {

            $this->guard()->logout();

            $user->notify(new ConfirmEmail());

            return redirect(route('login'));
        }
    }
}
```

this is the api register controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
use App\Models\Auth\User\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends  Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles user registration via REST API
    |
    */

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  RegisterRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        // attach role
        $role = \App\Models\Auth\Role\Role::where('name', 'user')->first();
        $user->roles()->attach($role);

        event(new Registered($user));

        $token = $user->createToken('Default')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(["token" => $token, "user" => User::find($user->id)]);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies user's mobile
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function verifyMobile(Request $request)
    {
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'mobile_number' => 'required|string|exists:users,mobile_number'
        ])->validate();

        $user = User::where('mobile_number', $request->mobile_number)->first();
        $user->mobile_verified = 1;
        $user->save();

        $token = $user->createToken('Default')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(["token" => $token, "user" => $user]);
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ])->validate();

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = Password::broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? response()->json(["message" => "Email Sent"])
            : response()->json(["message" => "Email Not Sent"], 400);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\Auth\User\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is register request code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'mobile' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ];
    }
}
```

and this is login controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        /*
         * Remove the socialite session variable if exists
         */

        \Session::forget(config('access.socialite_session_name'));

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  mixed $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (config('auth.users.confirm_email') && !$user->confirmed) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.notconfirmed', ['url' => route('confirm.send', [$user->email])])];
        }

        if (!$user->active) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => __('auth.active')];
        }

        if(!$user->hasRole('administrator')) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => 'Only administrator can login'];
        }

        if ($errors) {
            auth()->logout();  //logout

            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors($errors);
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

and this is api login controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users via REST API
    |
    */

    public function authenticate(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $username = filter_var($request->login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'mobile';

        if (Auth::attempt([$username => $request->login, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $token = $user->createToken('Default')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(["token" => $token, "user" => $user]);
        }
        return response()->json(["error" => "Invalid Login"], 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't read your codes completely. have you got your answer? If I answer how to register with phone number instead of email would your problem be solved?

Comment: Yes if you answer it will be solved

Comment: Waiting for you

Comment: it's okay my friend

Comment: Still waiting for you